# Error: Must Implement insert(Object obj)

Tags: java

Error in MutableBST class, that it must implement insert(Object obj). But I do not have method with Object parameter.

```
    public interface MutableSet<T>  {

        String insert(T obj); 

    }

    public class MutableBST<T> implements MutableSet   { 


        public String insert(T obj) {

            return "insert"; 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class implements `MutableSet` not `MutableSet<T>` so it implements with T being Object.

Answer (score 0):

You class `MutableBST<T>` should implement `MutableSet<T>`

```
class MutableBST<T> implements MutableSet<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the interface you are implementing, like this:

```
public interface MutableSet<T>  {

    String insert(T obj); 

}

// Implements MutableSet with the parameterized type T
public class MutableBST<T> implements MutableSet<T>   { 


    public String insert(T obj) {

        return "insert"; 
    } 
}
```